# Can we render the page newly in-between by service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

In my web-application, i created a offline html page and i wrote a service worker like if the network went off it should return offline page for all request. By that if any request triggered in offline state, service worker will return offline html page in response. But offline html is not displaying in the page. If i refresh the page offline html page. This is due to, while fetching original html page on refreshing the page, sw identify that the notwork is not there and so it is returning offline page.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
        try {
            const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
            return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);

            const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
            const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
            return cachedResponse;
        }
    })());
})
```

Is there any way to display the offline page without page refresh. That is i want to remove older html page and display offline page once i went to offline and triggered any request.

Comment: Can you share your fetch event handler code to display Offline page functionality?

Comment: I referred from this link - https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think service worker can go that, since, it runs in a separate thread all together and has doesn't even have access to window/document object as main thread does. What you can do is, detect if user is online/offline in your application, and can then render the offline HTML.
All the major browsers are now supporting the `navigator.onLine` boolean, or you can even attach event listener to detect the change, and write logic to show your offline HTML.

```
window.addEventListener('online', () => {...})
window.addEventListener('offline', () => {...})
```

For browser support details: https://caniuse.com/online-status

Comment: Thank you for help @kanishk Anand. This will help me. I am having another one doubt, can we able to refresh the current page from service worker ( i.e without using main thread )?

Comment: or able to re-paint the whole page by service worker with another html in sevice worker ( without main thread )?

Comment: No @LiterallyNoOne. Consider service worker to act as interceptor between your page and server. It cannot affect the page directly, but acts as a helper. For any DOM related changes, you need to incorporate that logic in your main application.